# Fixed div container with intentional data loss

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, containers

How can I create a fixed div container on a page so that when the page width shrinks, the elements within the container remain static and simply overflow off of both the left and right sides of the page? I also need the container to remain centered on the page without any horizontal scrolling.

Large width:
[image]

Smaller width:
[image]

I tried using `white-space: nowrap; overflow-x: hidden` but this is not working for me. In the above example, there are 7 different boxes (imagine these being 7 different images), which I can repeat  in case the screen width becomes very wide.

Comment: Boxes 3 and 5 in the second image should be cut off, not shrunken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to work with this. Isn't it what you are looking for? However it depends on knowing the total width of the container block - you can calculate this while page load with js (or simplier by jQuery).

So the .static-container must be of .block-items width (including margins), and the css attribute "left" of the .static-container must be a half of its total width.

Sorry if it does not look PRO for you, just handtyped this short idea right now :)

As for the auto repeat - well, it seems that you need to live-check the screen width, duplicate items in DOM and re-calculate .static-container while screen width changes. I assume your items are not the background, which can be x-repeated...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<style type='text/css'>
.main-container { position:relative;width:100%;height:100px;background:red;overflow:hidden }
.static-container { position:absolute;width:700px;margin-left:50%;left:-350px;height:80px;background:green; }
.block-items { float:left;margin:5px;width:60px;height:60px;background:orange; }
</style>

<div class='main-container'>
    <div class='static-container'>
        <div class='block-items'>1</div>
        <div class='block-items'>2</div>
        <div class='block-items'>3</div>
        <div class='block-items'>4</div>
        <div class='block-items'>5</div>
        <div class='block-items'>6</div>
        <div class='block-items'>7</div>
        <div class='block-items'>8</div>
        <div class='block-items'>9</div>
        <div class='block-items'>10</div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are targeting browsers which support [`flexbox`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), [CSS3 selectors](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) and [`@media`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_at-rules_media) then you use a `@media` rule to define the `width` at which the start and end elements should have `display: none` applied.

Using `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-around;` keeps the children spaced evenly across the page. The defaults for `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, and `flex-basis` allow the children to shrink (as seen in your image) but not grow - it is the space that grows. Finally, the `margin` keeps some space between the children as the page is narrowed.

Solution also as a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lybrqetk/), since the output pane is easier to drag to collapse the width and see the desired output

**Update:** addressed comments for keeping width/height of children fixed by specifying no flex-grow and a fixed `flex-basis: 100px` with `flex: 0 0 100px` - also see [updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3Lhrcu5w/)

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  margin: 0 10px;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
}

@media (max-width: 820px) {
  .box:first-child,
  .box:last-child {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 620px) {
  .box:nth-child(2),
  .box:nth-last-child(2) {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 420px) {
  .box:nth-child(3),
  .box:nth-last-child(3) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
  <div class="box">7</div>
</section>
```

Comment: This is a nice solution. The only problem is that the `.box` element's width grows/shrinks as the container width changes whereas I need these to be a static width & height

Comment: That's just because of the defaults I explained in the answer. It might be fixed by fiddling with `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, and `flex-basis`. Also, your image shows a box shrinking in width so I assumed you wanted this

Comment: Ah yeah maybe that wasn't clear. The image was supposed to be showing the boxes on the left and right being cut off

Comment: Sure, I get that part but boxes 3 and 5 are clearly narrower. Anyway, I’ve updated my solution to fit the clarified requirements

Answer (score 0):

This could be the type of question where you want to achieve X asking for Y while Z can be a better options.

I'm not sure why you want to use fixed positioning at all, this means the images describe something other than positioning but rather the flow of the elements.

Anyway If i understand what you want correctly, you can do that using flexBox,

```
.centered_content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately flex is not backward compatible with older browsers

Comment: Flexbox actually has pretty great support even in some older browsers. Just like anything else IE 6-9 do not do a great job of supporting and IE 10 and 11 have partial support. https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox There are workarounds for a lot of those features.

Comment: This solves a completely different requirement. As you can see from the screenshots in my post, I need the content to overflow off of the left and right sides of the page equally. Flexbox will always start with the left most image at the beginning of the page page

Comment: McLovin how my solution fit your needs?